# How to test if some specific rack middleware is being used?

Tags: ruby, testing, sinatra, rack, sentry

To be more particular, I'm talking about `sentry-raven` and `sinatra` here. I saw examples testing `sinatra` applications, or middlewares. But I didn't see ones testing if some particular middleware is present. Or should I be testing behavior, not configuration (or how should I call it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [`ruby-raven` guys](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby/issues/284), we've got this:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

# the app: start

require 'sinatra'
require 'sentry-raven'

Raven.configure(true) do |config|
  config.dsn = '...'
end

use Raven::Rack

get '/' do
  'Hello, world!'
end

# the app: end

require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

Raven.configure do |config|
  logger = ::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.level = ::Logger::WARN
  config.logger = logger
end

describe 'app' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    @app || Sinatra::Application
  end

  class TestRavenError < StandardError; end

  it 'sends errors to sentry' do
    @app = Class.new Sinatra::Application do
      get '/' do
        raise TestRavenError
      end
    end
    allow(Raven.client).to receive(:send).and_return(true)
    begin
      get '/'
    rescue TestRavenError
    end
    expect(Raven.client).to have_received(:send)
  end
end
```

Or if `raven` sending requests is in the way (when tests fail because of `raven` sending requests, and not because of the underlying error), one can disable them:

```
Raven.configure(true) do |config|
  config.should_send = Proc.new { false }
end
```

And mock `Raven.send_or_skip` instead:

```
...
allow(Raven).to receive(:send_or_skip).and_return(true)
begin
  get '/'
rescue TestRavenError
end
expect(Raven).to have_received(:send_or_skip)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The important thing (I'd say) is the behaviour, but if you wish to check for middleware there are 2 ways I'd suggest after taking a delve into the [Sinatra source](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra) (there are possibly much easier/better ways):

#### The env

In the Sinatra source [there's a method that uses the env to check if a middleware is already present](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L210):

```
# Behaves exactly like Rack::CommonLogger with the notable exception that it does nothing,
# if another CommonLogger is already in the middleware chain.
class CommonLogger < Rack::CommonLogger
  def call(env)
    env['sinatra.commonlogger'] ? @app.call(env) : super
  end
```

You could do the same thing in a route, e.g.

```
get "/env-keys" do
  env.keys.inspect
end
```

It'll only show you the middleware if it's inserted something in env hash, e.g.

```
class MyBad
  def initialize app, options={}
    @app = app
    @options = options
  end

  def call env
    @app.call env.merge("mybad" => "I'm sorry!")
  end
end
```

output:

```
["SERVER_SOFTWARE", "SERVER_NAME", "rack.input", "rack.version", "rack.errors", "rack.multithread", "rack.multiprocess", "rack.run_once", "REQUEST_METHOD", "REQUEST_PATH", "PATH_INFO", "REQUEST_URI", "HTTP_VERSION", "HTTP_HOST", "HTTP_CONNECTION", "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL", "HTTP_ACCEPT", "HTTP_USER_AGENT", "HTTP_DNT", "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE", "SERVER_PORT", "QUERY_STRING", "SERVER_PROTOCOL", "rack.url_scheme", "SCRIPT_NAME", "REMOTE_ADDR", "async.callback", "async.close", "rack.logger", "mybad", "rack.request.query_string", "rack.request.query_hash", "sinatra.route"]
```

It's near the end of that list.

#### The middleware method

[There's also a method called `middleware` in Sinatra::Base](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1187):

```
  # Middleware used in this class and all superclasses.
  def middleware
    if superclass.respond_to?(:middleware)
      superclass.middleware + @middleware
    else
      @middleware
    end
  end
```

Call it in the class definition of a modular app and you can get the middlewares in an array:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class AnExample < Sinatra::Base
  use MyBad
  warn "self.middleware = #{self.middleware}"
```

output:

```
self.middleware = [[MyBad, [], nil]]
```

There may be a way to get it from Sinatra::Application, but I haven't looked.

Comment: I didn't insist on testing not behavior. You can consider middleware being used if it manifest itself in one way or another. Additionally, I've got [an answer](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby/issues/284) from `raven-ruby` people. I didn't check it yet though.

Comment: @x-yuri If it manifests itself one way or the other then it will affect behaviour and you can check that. If it doesn't affect behaviour then where's the problem? "I didn't insist on testing not behavior." I don't know what this means.

Comment: `If it manifests itself one way or the other then it will affect behaviour and you can check that.` So I was asking how to check that. I might haven't made myself clear enough though. `I don't know what this means.` I'm fine with anybody showing me how to test behavior here, not state (or configuration, or whatever it is).

Comment: @x-yuri The [last comment](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby/issues/284#issuecomment-69910312) in the issue thread you linked to is good, probably [a mock with `should_receive`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-9/docs/message-expectations)

Comment: If you add this solution to your answer, I'll accept it.